# Calling a function with a variable changes the variable itself or just his copy?

Tags: java, arrays

it's Trumpy again!

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] ar){
    int[] a={1,2,3};
    int x=3;
    foo1(a);
    foo2(x);
    System.out.println(a[0]);
    System.out.println(x);
}
public static void foo1(int[] a){
    a[0]=55;
}
public static void foo2(int x){
    x=77;
}
```

The output:

```
55
3
```

Trumpy's question: when I call to `foo2` function it doesn't change the `x` variable, the change remained in the scope of the function. but when I call `foo1` it changes the array itslef, am I right?

Comment: It doesn't change the array, it changes one of the elements of the array. The array is still the same. if you do `a = new int[4]` you'll observe the exact same behaviour you see with `foo2` (`a` doesn't change in `main`).

Comment: In `foo1` you're changing a value in the array pointed to by the reference. In `foo2` you're changing the reference (and as it's passed by value this doesn't last outside the function).

Comment: Dammm 4896 upvotes and I have zero

Comment: why closing so fast? what's bothering you?@BackSlash

Comment: @Trumpy Because some answers provided in the duplicate question already address your issue. You can take a look at [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40523/1759845), for example.